# Is it possible for forward stored files in AWS S3, for example automatically forward stored files to an email account

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have files stored in AWS S3 Bucket. Is it possible to automatically forward these files to an email account for example??

Comment: please improve your answer. Try to clear your goal, try to share your effort, you cannot only ask. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Answer (score 0):

Consider creating [pre-signed URLs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ShareObjectPreSignedURL.html) for the objects and then sending those URLs via email, instead of actually emailing the files.

For existing objects in S3: you can use any AWS SDK to enumerate objects in S3, create pre-signed URLs, and then send those URLs by email using [Amazon SES](https://aws.amazon.com/ses/) (or any third-party email service).

For new objects landing in S3: use [AWS Lambda](https://aws.amazon.com/lambda/) to respond to  s3:ObjectCreated:* events and your Lambda function, using an AWS SDK, can create pre-signed URLs and email them as needed.

Comment: Many thanks for your answer jarmod
what about when a file is uploaded into an S3 bucket, when it arrives, it is automatically forwarded on to a particular email address???

Comment: That's covered in the "For new objects landing in S3" part of my answer. Lambda is event-driven. You can configure the S3 service to automatically invoke any desired Lambda function when an object is uploaded. If you want to write a Lambda function that forwards the object by email, you can do that (though I would suggest a time-limited, pre-signed URL may often be preferable).